# JSON_VALUE value returning NULL instead of actual value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table in that one column contains jsonstring.While trying to read value from json result coming as `NULL` instead of name value.
**query:**

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(value, '$.UUID') as uuid, 
       JSON_VALUE(value, '$.name') as name
FROM (select * 
      from openjson('[{
  "UUID": "123",
  "name": "data:image/png;base64,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"
}]')) ojson
```

**Result:**

[image: NullResult]

Why and How to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally suggest using `OPENJSON` with a `WITH` clause:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'[{
  "UUID": "123",
  "name": "data:image/png;base64,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"
}]';

SELECT UUID,
       [Name]
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
     WITH (UUID int,
           [name] nvarchar(MAX)) OJ;
```

As for *why* you got `NULL`, that's covered in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value):

> ### Return value
>
> Returns a single text value of type nvarchar(4000). The collation of the returned value is the same as the collation of the input expression.
>
> **If the value is greater than 4000 characters:**
>
> - **In lax mode, JSON_VALUE returns null.**
> - **In strict mode, JSON_VALUE returns an error.**
>
> If you have to return scalar values greater than 4000 characters, use OPENJSON instead of JSON_VALUE. For more info, see [OPENJSON (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

I've added emphasis to the relevant part. The value of `[name]` in your example is 14322 characters; well over 4000. As you can see, the documentation also recommends the method I used.